# Is there a good editor for OpenSCAD?

Tags: openscad

I'm novice at OpenSCAD, is there an editor with language supports for OpenSCAD? I need the code auto-completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in editor does have auto-complete support but limited to the language features.

There's other options like:

- VSCode support
  https://github.com/Leathong/openscad-support-vscode
- Plugin for JetBrains IDEs
  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11198-openscad-language-support

You can also check the section in the Manual about [Using an external Editor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Using_an_external_Editor_with_OpenSCAD) for some extra info.